# How to get childData inside a key

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, for-loop

i created a script where i grouped the data based on their moduleId.

here is the sample json

```
{
    "1": [{
        "id": 1,
        "moduleId": "1",
        "dropdownModuleName": "NL",
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": "1",
        "updatedBy": null,
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 17:37:21",
        "dateUpdated": null
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "moduleId": "1",
        "dropdownModuleName": "EE",
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": null,
        "updatedBy": null,
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 18:01:39",
        "dateUpdated": null
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "moduleId": "1",
        "dropdownModuleName": "SA",
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": null,
        "updatedBy": "1",
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 18:01:46",
        "dateUpdated": "2018-09-19 18:10:02"
    }],
    "4": [{
        "id": 4,
        "moduleId": "4",
        "dropdownModuleName": "CON",
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": null,
        "updatedBy": "1",
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 18:01:56",
        "dateUpdated": "2018-09-19 18:13:33"
    }, {
        "id": 5,
        "moduleId": "4",
        "dropdownModuleName": "XPO",
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": "1",
        "updatedBy": null,
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 18:38:41",
        "dateUpdated": null
    }, {
        "id": 6,
        "moduleId": "4",
        "dropdownModuleName": "RG",
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": "1",
        "updatedBy": null,
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 19:13:00",
        "dateUpdated": null
    }],
    "5": [{
        "id": 7,
        "moduleId": "5",
        "dropdownModuleName": "REG",
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": "1",
        "updatedBy": null,
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 19:13:18",
        "dateUpdated": null
    }, {
        "id": 8,
        "moduleId": "5",
        "dropdownModuleName": "COM",
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": "1",
        "updatedBy": null,
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 19:13:28",
        "dateUpdated": null
    }, {
        "id": 9,
        "moduleId": "5",
        "dropdownModuleName": "BEE",
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": "1",
        "updatedBy": null,
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 19:13:35",
        "dateUpdated": null
    }, {
        "id": 10,
        "moduleId": "5",
        "dropdownModuleName": "CA,
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": "1",
        "updatedBy": null,
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 19:13:44",
        "dateUpdated": null
    }, {
        "id": 11,
        "moduleId": "5",
        "dropdownModuleName": "PPC",
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": "1",
        "updatedBy": null,
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 19:13:51",
        "dateUpdated": null
    }, {
        "id": 12,
        "moduleId": "5",
        "dropdownModuleName": "TIC",
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": "1",
        "updatedBy": null,
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 19:13:58",
        "dateUpdated": null
    }]
}
```

the way i did this is by using this script.

```
newBody = JSON.parse(body);

newJson = _.groupBy(newBody,function (o) {
    return o.moduleId
})
nBody = JSON.stringify(newJson)
```

what i wanted to do is to get the `dropdownModuleName`,`moduleId` etc inside the json after ajax success request.. so what i did was to loop the result. what happen was there is no result that was showing on my console...

here is my ajax request.

```
 $.ajax({
     url:'/api/navbarToggleDropdownMenu/getall',
     type:'GET',
     dataType:'JSON',
     success:function (res) {
         console.log(res);
         for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            console.log(res[i])
         }
    }
})
```

the 1st console returns the json on my above post.. but the console inside for loop didn't return a result

Comment: did you receive any error?

Comment: nope i didn't receive any error.. i think i messed up my loop..still finding a way

Comment: but did the console above loop displayed successfully?

Comment: the result of the first console is the json i posted above.

Comment: You are not getting an array as the response, you have an object. You can use `Object.keys()` to iterate through your object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace your loop with something like this

```
for (var i in res) {
  console.log(res[i]);
}
```

```js
var res = {
    "1": [{
        "id": 1,
        "moduleId": "1",
        "dropdownModuleName": "NL",
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": "1",
        "updatedBy": null,
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 17:37:21",
        "dateUpdated": null
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "moduleId": "1",
        "dropdownModuleName": "EE",
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": null,
        "updatedBy": null,
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 18:01:39",
        "dateUpdated": null
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "moduleId": "1",
        "dropdownModuleName": "SA",
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": null,
        "updatedBy": "1",
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 18:01:46",
        "dateUpdated": "2018-09-19 18:10:02"
    }],
    "4": [{
        "id": 4,
        "moduleId": "4",
        "dropdownModuleName": "CON",
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": null,
        "updatedBy": "1",
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 18:01:56",
        "dateUpdated": "2018-09-19 18:13:33"
    }, {
        "id": 5,
        "moduleId": "4",
        "dropdownModuleName": "XPO",
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": "1",
        "updatedBy": null,
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 18:38:41",
        "dateUpdated": null
    }, {
        "id": 6,
        "moduleId": "4",
        "dropdownModuleName": "RG",
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": "1",
        "updatedBy": null,
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 19:13:00",
        "dateUpdated": null
    }],
    "5": [{
        "id": 7,
        "moduleId": "5",
        "dropdownModuleName": "REG",
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": "1",
        "updatedBy": null,
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 19:13:18",
        "dateUpdated": null
    }, {
        "id": 8,
        "moduleId": "5",
        "dropdownModuleName": "COM",
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": "1",
        "updatedBy": null,
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 19:13:28",
        "dateUpdated": null
    }, {
        "id": 9,
        "moduleId": "5",
        "dropdownModuleName": "BEE",
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": "1",
        "updatedBy": null,
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 19:13:35",
        "dateUpdated": null
    }, {
        "id": 10,
        "moduleId": "5",
        "dropdownModuleName": "CA",
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": "1",
        "updatedBy": null,
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 19:13:44",
        "dateUpdated": null
    }, {
        "id": 11,
        "moduleId": "5",
        "dropdownModuleName": "PPC",
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": "1",
        "updatedBy": null,
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 19:13:51",
        "dateUpdated": null
    }, {
        "id": 12,
        "moduleId": "5",
        "dropdownModuleName": "TIC",
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": "1",
        "updatedBy": null,
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 19:13:58",
        "dateUpdated": null
    }]
}

for (var i in res) {
    console.log(res[i])
}
```

Comment: i tried doing a nested loop.. but when i got the result this also show up on my console. `ƒ (){for(var t,e,o=this.length;o--;)t=Math.floor(Math.random()*o),e=this[o],this[o]=this[t],this[t]=e;return this}`

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the response above then the problem could be on

```
res[i]
```

res is an object based on the curly braces. The id becomes res's property so accessing it would be res.1 but numbers does not comply with javascripts identifiers/ variable names.

Try adding another level for the reponse but using a different key?

EDIT: or another method, like looping over properties
e.g

```
for (var property1 in res) { 
    res[property1]; } // here is the value 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use nested loop to find the child value ... in below example i have you `$.each nested function` and print `console.log('moduleId-' + v.moduleId +' '+'dropdownModuleName-'+ v.dropdownModuleName)`

```js
var data = {
    "1": [{
        "id": 1,
        "moduleId": "1",
        "dropdownModuleName": "NL",
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": "1",
        "updatedBy": null,
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 17:37:21",
        "dateUpdated": null
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "moduleId": "1",
        "dropdownModuleName": "EE",
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": null,
        "updatedBy": null,
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 18:01:39",
        "dateUpdated": null
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "moduleId": "1",
        "dropdownModuleName": "SA",
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": null,
        "updatedBy": "1",
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 18:01:46",
        "dateUpdated": "2018-09-19 18:10:02"
    }],
    "4": [{
        "id": 4,
        "moduleId": "4",
        "dropdownModuleName": "CON",
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": null,
        "updatedBy": "1",
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 18:01:56",
        "dateUpdated": "2018-09-19 18:13:33"
    }, {
        "id": 5,
        "moduleId": "4",
        "dropdownModuleName": "XPO",
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": "1",
        "updatedBy": null,
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 18:38:41",
        "dateUpdated": null
    }, {
        "id": 6,
        "moduleId": "4",
        "dropdownModuleName": "RG",
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": "1",
        "updatedBy": null,
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 19:13:00",
        "dateUpdated": null
    }],
    "5": [{
        "id": 7,
        "moduleId": "5",
        "dropdownModuleName": "REG",
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": "1",
        "updatedBy": null,
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 19:13:18",
        "dateUpdated": null
    }, {
        "id": 8,
        "moduleId": "5",
        "dropdownModuleName": "COM",
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": "1",
        "updatedBy": null,
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 19:13:28",
        "dateUpdated": null
    }, {
        "id": 9,
        "moduleId": "5",
        "dropdownModuleName": "BEE",
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": "1",
        "updatedBy": null,
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 19:13:35",
        "dateUpdated": null
    }, {
        "id": 10,
        "moduleId": "5",
        "dropdownModuleName": "CA",
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": "1",
        "updatedBy": null,
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 19:13:44",
        "dateUpdated": null
    }, {
        "id": 11,
        "moduleId": "5",
        "dropdownModuleName": "PPC",
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": "1",
        "updatedBy": null,
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 19:13:51",
        "dateUpdated": null
    }, {
        "id": 12,
        "moduleId": "5",
        "dropdownModuleName": "TIC",
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": "1",
        "updatedBy": null,
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 19:13:58",
        "dateUpdated": null
    }]
}
$.each(data, function(key, value){
    $.each(value, function(k,v){
        console.log('moduleId-' + v.moduleId +' '+'dropdownModuleName-'+ v.dropdownModuleName)

    })
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code may get result in your console.

replace your for loop with this below code.

```
var responseObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res));
    $.each(responseObj.d, function (index, el) {
        console.log("Id:- "+el.id+" Module Id:- "+ el.moduleId
        +" Module Name:- "+el.dropdownModuleName);
});
```